# How to convert an NSString to char

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, char

I am trying to convert an `NSString` to a `ResType`, as defined below in `MacTypes.h`.

```
FourCharCode // A 32-bit value made by packing four 1 byte characters together
typedef FourCharCode ResType;
```

I think I could use `[aString getCharacters:range:]`, but is there a more straight forward way to make this conversion?

After trying suggestions from David, here is some further information.

I am using GTResourceFork, a Cocoa wrapper for accessing resource forks. The method I am calling is:
    - (NSArray *)usedResourcesOfType: (ResType)type;

If I hard code a value of 'RTF ', I get the results I expect. I cannot figure out how to convert an NSString containing "RTF " to the hard-coded value. I created a test case using NSString's getCharacters and getBytes, and they all give me different integer values. How can I convert the NSString to give me the same integer value as the hard-coded one?

```
 Method used:       Value:  Casted int value:
 Hard Coded(Works): 'RTF ' '1381254688'
 getCharacters:     'RTF ' '5505106'
 getBytes(ASCII):   'RTF ' '541480018'
 getBytes(UTF8):    'RTF ' '541480018'
```

Thanks in advance,
Lance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `getCharacters:range:` is that it gives you UTF-16 characters (`unichar`s), whereas you want ASCII.

`*(ResType*)[aString UTF8String]` will convert the string to UTF-8 (which is equivalent to ASCII as long as all the characters in the string fit within the ASCII range) and then give you the first four bytes as a `ResType` value. Whether this is efficient enough depends on how often you want to do these conversions.

Another option is to use `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:` with the encoding set to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` or `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, the destination buffer set to a pointer to an existing `ResType` variable, and the maximum length set to `4` (or `sizeof (ResType)`).

---

### Update:

I've figured out why you're not getting the correct result with my suggestion. It turns out that in four-character integer literals, the bytes are stored in the opposite order to how they're written. Here's an example:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() {
    int code = 'RTF ';
    printf("'%c%c%c%c' = %d\n", ((char*)&code)[0], ((char*)&code)[1],
                                ((char*)&code)[2], ((char*)&code)[3],
                                code);
}
```

The output is `' FTR' = 1381254688`. So, if you want to convert from `NSString`s to these values, here are a few options:

- Copy the string into a four-byte buffer (using one of the methods I suggested) and then reverse it by swapping byte `0` with byte `3`, and byte `1` with byte `2`.
- The same, but do the reversing using a standard "endianness-swapping" algorithm like the one on [this page](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=292902).
- Iterate through first (and only) four characters using `characterAtIndex:`, and insert them into a four-byte buffer in reverse. Remember that `characterAtIndex:` returns a UTF-16 character, but this can be easily cast to as ASCII character assuming it is within the ASCII range.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. These methods did not work for me, however. I will add more information to my original question.

Comment: @Lance: I've figured out what the problem is and updated my answer with a few suggestions.

Comment: @David: were I needing to swap endianness, I'd use the built-in Cocoa functions for doing it like `NXByteSwap...()`. That way when Apple updates their architecture again (they've had four in recent history) the result is still likely to be correct.

Comment: @Graham: Good idea. For the benefit of the OP, could you post the full name of the function(s), or a documentation link? I would do it myself, but for some reason I can't find it.

Comment: @David/@Lance: `EndianU32_NtoB()` in Core Endian is one of many APIs to do the conversion.

Comment: Your update worked great David. And I'll take a look at Graham's suggestion to make the code cleaner and future proof. Thank you!