# Anyway to quickly break a word into an array of characters in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

For example: `NSString *strWord = "english";`

The result NSArray would be something like: e n g l i s h

I think is possible to do it with

[NSString componentSeparatedByCharacter:somecharacter], but I don't know what that character is...

I wrote something like this to extract the character:

```
NSString *character;
for (int i=0; i<[strWord length]; i++) {
    character = [strWord substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by a "character"?  An `NSString` holds a sequence of `unichar`, which is a UTF-16 character, but a single Unicode character may be represented by multiple UTF-16 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to enumerate them and support iOS 4.0 or later, you could use

```
[strWord enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [strWord length])
                            options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){
    // substring here contains each character in turn
}];
```

You could also just copy the characters into a buffer using `-getCharacters:range:` if you don't actually need them as an NSArray. Or you could just iterate over the string (using the block method, or by calling `-characterAtIndex:` repeatedly, or by copying out the entire buffer and iterating over that) and construct your own array.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would like to support version 3.2 and up.

Comment: The suggestions given in the second paragraph all work all the way back to iOS 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];
for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}
```

You can also use this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCharacters:range:

Take a look here for more options:

[NSString to char[]](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/142601-nsstring-to-char.html)

[How to convert an NSString to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797037/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-char)

Comment: This code here leaks the characters array. you should probably just use `[NSMutableArray array]`. Your code will also fail if the character is non-ASCII - you want the %C format token instead for a unichar.